# Top network post URL bug for migrated posts

Tags: bug, profile-page, migrated-questions, top-network-posts

I tried to see if this rare bug was brought up before, but I didn't find anything.

The following profiles:

- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/3677
- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/16724
- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/32094

... have top posts like this:

[image: missing title]

A missing title, and the link goes to, for example:

- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147482070/124782#124782

... which is 404 page not found, but the post is alive here:

- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124782#124782

All those posts were migrated as @Arulkumar noted in a comment here, so the issue seems to be with the migration.

Comment: Seems the post is migrated from [Aviation to Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/124781/timeline#history_f2c3adf1-7c8d-43dc-bebb-fbd3aeea8dea).

Comment: Wow, that’s really weird.